# how to make edittext and alertdialog has same width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

a alertdialog include a edittext

how to make edittext's width same with the alertdialog's (NO ABSOLUTE LAYOUT) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom alertDialog and use the following code:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) activity.getViewById(R.id.myEditText);
myEditText.setLayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Give that a try.

Comment: userName=(EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.userEditText);
userName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

Comment: like this ? but when i modify code like this, it's cannot open my app